# Pandas dataframe value set with a copy warning despite assignment with .iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know the issue around setting the value of a slice of a df has been addressed thoroughly here.

However, as far as I can tell, I'm assigning the value correctly to not trigger the warning - what is going on here? Is it just the use of the original value + 1 that is causing the warning?

```
df.iloc[df_row_idx]['n_sites_recruiting'] = df.iloc[df_row_idx]['n_sites'] + 1
```

Comment: You need to use `loc`. Like, `df.loc[df_row_idx, 'n_sites_recruiting'] = ...`

Comment: Thanks this works, seems like the simplest solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not the correct syntax, you need to provide the index of both rows and columns,

```
df_col_idx =  df.columns.get_loc("n_sites_recruiting")
df_col_idx2 =  df.columns.get_loc("n_sites")
df.iloc[df_row_idx, df_col_idx] = df.iloc[df_row_idx, df_col_idx2] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Simply

```
df.iloc[:]['n_sites_recruiting'] = df.iloc[:]['n_sites'] + 1
```

Or even:

```
df.loc[:,'n_sites_recruiting'] = df.loc[:,'n_sites'] + 1
```

Comment: this only works if you want to assign a single value (i.e size of df_row_idx is 1)

Comment: True.  It could be put into a loop, but I didn't even think about vector function.
How un-pythonic of me.